# sql application on a new pc

Tags: mysql, qt

Given a new PC with only windows installed. What are the prerequisites to ensure that an qt sql application runs on it.

Premise.
I have copied in bin folder the following
libmySQL.dll
libqsqlmysql4.a
mingwm10.dll
QtCored4.dll
QtSqld4.dll
QtCore4.dll
QtGuid4.dll
libqsqlmysqld4.a

and in plugins/sqldrivers , have copied the following

qsqlodbcd4.dll
qsqlmysqld4.dll
qsqlodbc4.dll
qsqlmysql4.dll
qsqlited4.dll
libqsqlodbcd4.a
qsqlite4.dll
libqsqlmysqld4.a
libqsqlmysqld4.a
libqsqlodbc4.a
libqsqlited4.a
libqsqlmysql4.a
libqsqlite4.a

yet on some pc and application with simple sql query like the following works and others it does not. what do i need to fill up.

```
QString queryString = "SELECT * FROM XXXXXX WHERE XXXX_XXX_XXX = \"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"";
```

Brgds,

kNish

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you setup Sql Database Drivers correctly on all PCs?

Here you can find how to do:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html